# Edit NewFrom.aspx or make a new one?

Tags: list, document-library, sharepoint-online, content-type, form

I have a Doc Libary on my SharePoint where i now got a folder content type.
What i want to do is that when i go to new document i press on IFUSimon to make it a folder:

[image]

And then we get to this:
[image]

In here i want my own "survey page" insteed of this one and still it going to save as a folder.

I have mange to open the item in my own "survey/form" and to save to the same item.

[image]

So in this picture is what i want in my NewForm.aspx (and ofcours the fields are going to be empty) and it's should be saved as a folder like usual.

[image]

Comment if you need more information please!!

Answer (score 0):

It is safer to keep a copy of the initial NewForm.aspx in case you (or anyone else) break anything.

Comment: ok can i replace the code in new form eith my code and in hsarepoint desigern what code in newForm can i remove?

Comment: First of all, make sure you edit the correct NewForm that is for your IFUSimon content type.

Comment: I'm in Sharepoint designer now under content type/IFUSimon but cant find NewForm you now where it is?

Comment: Can i do something with the content type ID to use my own form?